# Replace database Mirroring Principle Server

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I have been asked to look at the steps required to replace a Windows 2012 R2 Server that is used as the Principle Mirroring server due to it being "sized" wrongly at the time of design.
I'm just looking to see what steps to use that would be the best way to achieve this? I was thinking the following but would appreciate if there may be an easier less disruptive way of doing it? Thanks

1. Manual Failover the databases so the Mirror is now the Principle and the Principle is now the Mirror
2. Remove Database Mirroring
3. Remove the "old" windows server that originally was the Principle
4. Bring online the "new" windows server and setup SQL Server
5. Re-establish mirroring between the 2 servers through setting up mirroring steps
6. Manual Failover the databases so the new server is acting as the principle

Comment: Are these physical or virtual?

Comment: Hi Erik, There all physical

Comment: Are you using Standard or Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Hi Andrew, It's 2012 SP2 Standard edition.

Comment: Hi, Just wondering if the steps above sound the least disruptive? Thanks

Comment: Your steps are probably the best way to go. I'd just add backup prior to performing any tasks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. These steps worked with minimal disruption :)